# Prove $\gcd(a, b) = \gcd(b, r)$ using the fact that $\gcd(a, b) ≤ \gcd(b, r)$ and $\gcd(b, r ) ≤ \gcd(a, b)$

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

In my textbook I came across this lemma:

> [image: lemma 4.8.2]

> [image]

The problem is that they use this premise:

> To prove that $A = B$, prove that $A ≤ B$ and that $B ≤ A$.

Also:

> [The proof is divided into two sections: (1) proof that $\gcd(a, b) ≤ \gcd(b, r )$, and (2)
> proof that $\gcd(b, r ) ≤ \gcd(a, b)$. Since each gcd is less than or equal to the other, the
> two must be equal.]

I want some explanation as to why it works, since I do not understand.
Note that I am still figuring proves related to GCD.

Comment: Take two sets. One with all numbers less than or equal to $A$ and one with all numbers greater than or equal to $A$. What is the intersection of those two sets?

Comment: ok, its A.  For example, A=4 then set B is numbers less than or equal 4 and set c is all numbers greater than or equal to 4. so, B and C share 4 in common. the problem is how to know that the first set and the second set will be the same number.

Comment: @Omar you don't "know" that; thats what the conditions $A\leq B$ and $B\leq A$ are for

Comment: Ok now I understand. 